# Calculate average rating of 5 ratings

Tags: php

How can calculate this array:

```
$ratings = [
    1 => 220,
    2 => 31,
    3 => 44,
    4 => 175,
    5 => 3188
];
```

To a number (the average vote) like:

```
4
```

or

```
3.5
```

Comment: Neither 4 or 3.5 is the average of the ratings you posted.

Comment: @Daan, not part of the question.

Comment: You should be more clearer. Why do you want 4 or 3.5 returned?

Comment: Think a bit about it: what exactly do you want to compute? Start with an item without any ratings. Add a rating, let's say 3 stars. What is average now? Why? Add another rating, let's say 4 stars. What is the average rating now and why? Iterate a couple of times more and find the formula yourself, it's not that difficult.

Answer (score 3):

The basic way to calculate the average is simply to add everything up, and divide it by the total number of values, so:

```
$total = array_sum($ratings);
$avg = $total/count($ratings);
printf('The average is %.2f', $avg);
```

The same logic applies to your values, only you need the average rating, so let's get the total number *"rating points"* that were given, and divide them by the total number of votes:

```
$totalStars = 0;
$voters = array_sum($ratings);
foreach ($ratings as $stars => $votes)
{//This is the trick, get the number of starts in total, then
 //divide them equally over the total nr of voters to get the average
    $totalStars += $stars * $votes;
}
printf(
    '%d voters awarded a total of %d stars to X, giving an average rating of %.1f',
    $voters,
    $totalStars,
    $totalStars/$voters
);
```

As you can [see here](https://eval.in/244673), the output is:

> 3658 voters awarded a total of 17054 stars to X, giving an average rating of 4.7

Answer (score 0):

Divide the total numbers of stars to the total number of votes:

```
$average = array_sum(array_map(
        function($nbStars, $howManyVotes) {
            return $nbStars * $howManyVotes;
        },
        array_keys($ratings),         // the stars: 1, 2, ... 5
        array_values($ratings)        // the votes for each nb. of stars
    )) / array_sum(array_values($ratings));
```

Comment: i belive that this will work for you guys                                                                                        $result['total_star'] = $this->db->select_sum('course_rating_start')->where('course_id',$course_id)->get('course_rating_review')->row();                     
 $result['total_rating'] = $this->db->where('course_id',$course_id)->count_all_results('course_rating_review');                                                                           $avg = $total_star/$total_rating;

Answer (score -1):

Add 220 times a rating of 1, 31 times a rating of 2 and so on. Then divide by the total.

```
<?php

$ratings = Array (
    1 => 220,
    2 => 31,
    3 => 44,
    4 => 175,
    5 => 3188
);

$max = 0;
$n = 0;
foreach ($ratings as $rate => $count) {
    echo 'Seen ', $count, ' ratings of ', $rate, "\n";
    $max += $rate * $count;
    $n += $count;
}

echo 'Average rating: ', $max / $n, "\n";

?>
```